# Return to a position in a list after displaying the card details with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list in a ng-repeat after the user enters an item in the list and then back to the list, I would like it to come back with the list open but with the screen over the item he just saw instead of returning to start the list.

P.S.: The need is that he continue to display the previous cards as well. Reason: This is a creature list. he went in to view her data and returned to the list. the ideal is to return to the position he was in, but when the list is returned at position 0 of the array.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify your question to meet that standards outlined there.

Comment: Resolved as follows:
$timeout(function () {
                $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('main').anchorScroll("#" + $location.hash('item' + itemId));
            }, 500);